# Android ToolBar showAsAction="withText", how to swap icon/text?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Thanks for any help you can give me, I have tried searching this issue but it seems no one else has the issue I have.

My issue currently is while this code works, and puts a checkbox icon with the words "Select/Deselect All" next to it like I want it, it puts them in the wrong order.  I want the words to come first and then have the icon/checkbox displayed to the right of it, but currently it puts the icon/checkbox to the left and the text to the right.  Is there a way to swap them around?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
  android:id="@+id/menu_select_all"
  android:title="Select/Deselect All"
  app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
  android:icon="@drawable/checked_checkbox"
  android:text="Select/Deselect All"/>
</menu>
```